# Does Google Cloud Functions support Node Version 8+

Tags: google-cloud-functions

The document in https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/ states that `firebase cloud functions` in production supports only Node v6.11.5.

I wish it supports the latest LTS version 8.9.4

Is the above link outdated or cloud functions still only support 6.11.5?

Comment: At the moment Cloud Functions runs 6.11.5. That won't change while it is in beta, but *may* change after that. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47712018/google-cloud-functions-node-js-8-9-x-lts-and-koa-library

Comment: Also see https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#supported_runtime_runtime_updates: "Cloud Functions offers Node.js runtime, currently in version v6.11.5. Where possible, we will follow the "LTS" release cycle of Node and will update minor and patch versions of the runtime as soon as or shortly after they become available." I guess the key here is "where possible".